# Custom migrate source plugin, extends FieldableEntity class, has migrate status of [error] No migrations found. Why?

Tags: entities, migrations

I'm writing a migrate source plugin for migrating D7 entityform (entityform module) submissions. If anyone has done this or knows an existing plugin, please let me know.

I am trying to extend the `FieldableEntity` base class from `Drupal\migrate_drupal\Plugin\migrate\source\d7\FieldableEntity;` because I want to use its `getFields()` and `getFieldValues()` methods when I override `prepareRow()` to include custom fields from my D7 entityform.

My problem is that when my source plugin extends `FieldableEntity`, drush reports `[error]  No migrations found.` for my migration. Importantly, however, if my source plugin instead uses the `SqlBase` class from `Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\source\SqlBase`, then drush can import all of my entityforms from D7 into D9 contact forms no problem. So it would seem that I am missing something when I try to implement `FieldableEntity` preventing it from retrieving data for the migration.

Here is my plugin, which shows up fine in `drush ms`:

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule_migrate\Plugin\migrate\source;

use Drupal\migrate\Row;
use Drupal\migrate_drupal\Plugin\migrate\source\d7\FieldableEntity;

/**
 * The 'mymodule_migrate_entityform' source plugin.
 *
 * @MigrateSource(
 *   id = "mymodule_migrate_entityform",
 *   source_module = "mymodule_migrate"
 * )
 */
class Entityform extends FieldableEntity {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function query() {
    $query = $this->select('entityform', 'e')
      ->fields('e', [
        'entityform_id',
        'type',
        'created',
        'changed',
        'uid'
      ]);
    return $query;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function fields() {
    return array(
      'entityform_id' => $this->t('The ID of the entityform submission.'),
      'type' => $this->t('The entityform type.'),
      'created' => $this->t('The time that the entityform was submitted.'),
      'changed' => $this->t('Last updated time.'),
      'uid' => $this->t('The {users}.uid who submitted the entityform. If set to 0, this entityform was submitted by an anonymous user.'),
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getIds() {
    $ids['entityform_id']['type'] = 'integer';
    $ids['entityform_id']['alias'] = 'e';
    return $ids;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function prepareRow(Row $row) {
    $entityform_id = $row->getSourceProperty('entityform_id');
    // Get Field API field values.
    foreach ($this->getFields('entityform', 'BUNDLE_MACHINE_NAME') as $field_name => $field) {
      $row->setSourceProperty($field_name, $this->getFieldValues('entityform', $field_name, $entityform_id));
    }
    return parent::prepareRow($row);
  }

}
```

I use this yml migration definition. My migrate destination is D8/D9 contact_message entity.

```yaml
id: mymodule_contact_message
label: D8 Contact message migration from D7 entityform submission
source:
  plugin: mymodule_migrate_entityform
process:
  id: entityform_id
  langcode:
    plugin: default_value
    source: language
    default_value: "und"
  created: created
  changed: changed
destination:
  plugin: entity:contact_message
  default_bundle: MY_DESTINATION_BUNDLE
```

As stated above, all of this works great when I use `SqlBase` in my plugin. But with `FieldableEntity` drush comes back with `[error] No migrations found.`

Comment: Maybe the namespace is wrong. Looking at other classes that extend FieldableEntity, such as Comment (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21source%21d7%21Comment.php/9.2.x), shows the namespace to be `\Drupal\[module]\Plugin\migrate\source\d7`

Comment: Than you for pointing that out @Jaypan, I corrected the namespace but my issue remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my problem when I identified a mistake in my `@MigrateSource` annotation on my plugin. I had included my own custom migration module in the `source_module` entry of the plugin annotation. Here is what I did wrong:

```php
/**
 * The 'mymodule_migrate_entityform' source plugin.
 *
 * @MigrateSource(
 *   id = "mymodule_migrate_entityform",
 *   source_module = "mymodule_migrate"
 * )
 */
```

Well I looked at the [api docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Annotation%21MigrateSource.php/property/MigrateSource%3A%3Asource_module/9.2.x) on `source_module`

> Identifies the system providing the data the source plugin will read.

> The source plugin itself determines how the value is used. For example, Migrate Drupal's source plugins expect source_module to be the name of a module that must be installed and enabled in the source database.

It didn't work because `source_module` was set to my D9 custom migration module, which is obviously not on the D7 source, so the migration just silently gets removed from the list of migrations.

So I simply deleted the annotation line. My working plugin annotation looks like this now, and the plugin extends `FieldableEntity` and works as I had hoped it would.

```php
/**
 * The 'mymodule_migrate_entityform' source plugin.
 *
 * @MigrateSource(
 *   id = "mymodule_migrate_entityform"
 * )
 */
```

I hope my plugin here will prove useful to someone migrating from D7 entityform to D8/9 core contact module (with contact_storage contrib module). It works.

Comment: Nice follow up.

Comment: thank you, you are my savior

Comment: glad to hear that it worked for you @tasqyn!